# Graphql - Not Authorized to access error message from AWS AppSync Amplify Console

Tags: reactjs, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm working with React + NextJs and have Amplify Graphql implemented. I'm logged in and set my current user as an Admin group, however, I'm not able to mutate a data based on authorId.

The logged in userId is **1234** (for example)

```
type Xp
  @model
  @key(name: "xpsByUserId", fields: ["authorId"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "authorId" }
      { allow: public, operations: [read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  authorId: ID!
  author: User @connection(fields: ["authorId"])
  name: String
  visibility: Visibility
  post: [Post] @connection(name: "XpPosts")
  createdAt: String
}
```

Trying to mutate:

```
mutation MyMutation {
  createXp(input: {authorId: "1234", name: "fdsfa"}) {
    id
    name
    author {
      username
    }
  }
}
```

I get a message: `Not Authorized to access createXp on type Xp`

This is my user type:

```
type User
  @model(subscriptions: null)
  @key(fields: ["userId"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "userId" }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  userId: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "postsByUserId", fields: ["userId"])
  xps: [Xp] @connection(keyName: "xpsByUserId", fields: ["userId"])
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
  following: [Following] @connection(keyName: "followingByUserId", fields: ["userId"])
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The user you are testing with, is its cognito sub corresponding to the authorId that you passing in to the mutation? The owner field is matching the cognito sub to what you pass in to / what is in the ownerField.

If this doesn't work, could you try to update your amplify graphql schema, in the xp model and the allow: owner line, to this and check if this works:

{ allow: owner, ownerField: "authorId", operations: [create, read, update, delete] }

Answer (score 1):

Try mentioning auth rules in Xp model like below as per [link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2926),

```
type Xp
  @model
  @key(name: "xpsByUserId", fields: ["authorId"])
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "authorId", operations: [create, delete, read, update] },
      { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"], operations: [create, delete, read, update]  },
      { allow: public, operations: [read] },
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  authorId: ID!
  author: User @connection(fields: ["authorId"])
  name: String
  visibility: Visibility
  post: [Post] @connection(name: "XpPosts")
  createdAt: String
}
```